# Maven sonar misconfiguration, maybe missing source directory?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

When I do a mvn clean package locally everything works fine. When I do a mvn clean package on the jenkins server I get errors. I am running Jenkins 1.596, Maven 3.2.5, SonarQube 4.5.1, Maven plug-in 2.4 is defined in the Jenkins sonar settings.

This is the output from the Jenkins job.

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5.1

INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myporject/target/sonar

[INFO] [22:48:12.147] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/target/sonar
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Source paths: src
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [22:48:12.148] Index files
[ERROR] File [relative=src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java, abs=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java] can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: File [relative=src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java, abs=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java] can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: File [relative=src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java, abs=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/src/test/java/com/blah/web/service.java] can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

It appears that something is missing from my Sonar plug-in settings but I'm not sure what or where to define it.

Here are some snippets from my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.blah</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>99</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myproject</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <routePath>${pom.project.build.directory}/routes</routePath>
    <spring.release.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.release.version>
    <rabbitmq.version>3.1.4</rabbitmq.version>
    <spring.amqp.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
</properties>
    <build>
    <finalName>myproject</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/java</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <classpathContainers>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    <classpathContainer>GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT</classpathContainer>
                </classpathContainers>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/integration/**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your source folder is a prefix of your test folder. In other words, if you say that your test folder is `src/test/java/`, your source folder should be `src/main/java`, not `src` since this causes the plugin to find the same class twice, which is what causes the error

Removing `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` should do the trick since it will use maven's default (src/main/java). While you're at it, remove also `testSourceDirectory` since you are setting it to the default value, so you don't need it. In general the pom should be as simple as possible since maven is all about convention over configuration

Comment: I removed all of the pointers to src, in the end it was a bad test that was causing the issue so I removed that too! Now it works.